# Why is this GET-request not finding my script?

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs

I'm getting an error when trying to set up a page with npm and grunt.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9997/bower_components/requirejs/require.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

The html it's having trouble with looks like this:

```
<script>
            var require = {
                baseUrl: '/',
                paths: {
                    'underscore': '/bower_components/underscore/underscore',
                    'backbone': '/bower_components/backbone/backbone',
                    'jquery': '/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
                    'react': '/bower_components/react/react',
                    'mustache': '/bower_components/mustache/mustache',
                    'mySite-assets': '.'
                }
            };
        </script>

//Specifically this next line:
        <script src="/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Any changes I make in the html-files revert back as soon as I run grunt. I have this problem in all of my html-files. I have a quite large project and I can't really figure out which config-file to change to solve this.

Comment: What does this have to do with node.js?

Comment: No clue. It was suggested as a tag and I'm using it so I just assumed it was appropriate. Is it not?

Comment: I don't see any node.js code above (server-side javascript), you should remove the tag so it doesn't show up in node.js tag queues

Comment: Check if `/bower_components` folder is served by your grunt script

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help @topheman!

I was looking in all the wrong places. The path in the grunt script to /bower_components was incorrect. After setting the correct path all of my html scripts are now free of this error.

Simply changed this line with the wrong path:

```
cwd: 'public/components',
```

into this line with the correct path:

```
cwd: 'bower_components',
```